# Django Model Reverse querying

Tags: python, django, model

I have 4 models, 
1) Item: describes the name and the value of the item. I can register new items completely independently.
2)A Line Item consists basically in one Item and the quantity of that specific item.
3)Inventory: Inventory is a bunch LineItems.
4) Survivor is just a user who owns the Inventory.
I not able to filter backwards the inventory.
Example: I want to get all the itens that the "x" user´s inventory has on it.
Survivor is my user.
Sorry for my bad english.

```
class Itens(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    points_value = models.FloatField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name

class LineItem(models.Model):
    itemln = models.ForeignKey(Itens,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='itens_contidos')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    inventory_ln = models.ForeignKey("Inventory",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Inventory(models.Model):

    survivor_inventory = models.OneToOneField(Survivor,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.survivor_inventory.name +' s inventory'


class Survivor(models.Model):

    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Iten.objects.filter(itens_contidos__inventory__survivor_inventory=my_survivor)
```

Note, your Inventory model is a bit strange - especially the `survivor_inventory` field; it points at a Survivor object, so it should probably just be called `survivor`.